# compile NITE2 for android platform

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk, nite

i try to compile nite2 for android platform
but it throw out some error ,
is there someone can answer my question?

> ash@XxAshxX:~/usr/NITE2/NiTE-2.0.0/Samples$ cd SimpleUserTracker/
>
> ash@XxAshxX:~/usr/NITE2/NiTE-2.0.0/Samples/SimpleUserTracker$ l
>
> main.cpp  Makefile
>
> ash@XxAshxX:~/usr/NITE2/NiTE-2.0.0/Samples/SimpleUserTracker$ PLATFORM=Arm make
>
> arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -MD -MP -MT "./../Bin/Intermediate/Arm-Release/SimpleUserTracker/main.d ../Bin/Intermediate/Arm-Release/SimpleUserTracker/main.o" -c -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp  -O3 -fno-tree-pre -fno-strict-aliasing -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math -funsafe-math-optimizations -fsingle-precision-constant -Wall --sysroot=/opt/ -O2 -DNDEBUG -I../../Include -I/home/ash/usr/OpenNI2-android/Include/  -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -o ../Bin/Intermediate/Arm-Release/SimpleUserTracker/main.o main.cpp
>
> In file included from /home/ash/usr/OpenNI2-android/Include/Linux-Arm/OniPlatformLinux-Arm.h:25,
>                    from /home/ash/usr/OpenNI2-android/Include/OniPlatform.h:43,
>                    from ../../Include/NiteCAPI.h:8,
>                    from ../../Include/NiTE.h:11,
>                    from main.cpp:8:
>
> /home/ash/usr/OpenNI2-android/Include/Linux-Arm/../Linux-x86/OniPlatformLinux-x86.h:31: fatal error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.
>
> make: *** [../Bin/Intermediate/Arm-Release/SimpleUserTracker/main.o] error 1

Answer (score 1):

Since SimpleUserTracker utilizes a proprietary NiTE2 library its not possible to compile this source code for arm platform.